# solving equations simultaneously 

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I have the following set of equations, and I want to solve them simultaneously for X and Y. I've been advised that I could use numpy to solve these as a system of linear equations. Is that the best option, or is there a better way?

```
a = (((f * X) + (f2 * X3 )) / (1 + (f * X) + (f2 * X3 ))) * i
b = ((f2 * X3 ) / (1 + (f * X) + (f2 * X3))) * i
c = ((f * X) / (1 + (j * X) + (k * Y))) * i
d = ((k * Y) / (1 + (j * X) + (k * Y))) * i 
f = 0.0001 
i = 0.001
j = 0.0001
k = 0.001 
e = 0 = X + a + b + c 
g = 0.0001 = Y + d 
h = i - a
```

Comment: In addition to `numpy`, which is probably the right answer, check out [sympy](https://code.google.com/p/sympy/).

Comment: I believe `numpy.solve(someMatrix)` would do quite nicely.

Comment: Thank you, both. I was also wondering whether I should install sympy or scipy. My understanding is that they overlap, but what is the benefit of one over the other? If you have had experience with either, I would appreciate the feedback. Thanks again.

Comment: scipy/numpy is for (fast) numerical work, sympy is for symbolic work. e.g. the equivalent of `solve(x^2 - 2 == 0)` will give the float `1.414213` in scipy, and an object representing `sqrt(2)` exactly in sympy. i.e. they are different.

Comment: What is `X3`? Is it a seperate variable or `X` cubed?

Comment: Sorry,it was supposed to be x^3

Comment: Well, you have a system of non-linear equations in terms of `X` and `Y`. If you need `X` and `Y`, linear algebra can't directly solve this problem.  A symbolic solver like `sympy` (or maple or mathematica) might be more help.  Alternately, you could go for a non-linear numerical solution.

Comment: This is a really ill-conditioned problem. You have to be careful on solving it. The solution lies near `X=-1000` and `Y=-0.0001` for the values given.

Comment: I found additional solutions exist near `X=0`, `Y=-100` and `X=0`, `Y=0.001`. Look at Worlfram alpha link, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B-%28X%5E3+%28Y%2B100%29%2B100+X%5E2%2B2000+X+%28Y%2B200%29%2B3000000+%28Y%2B100%29%29%2F%28100+%28X%2B10+%28Y%2B100%29%29+%28X%5E3%2B1000+X%2B1000000%29%29%2BX%2B3%2F1000%3D0%2CY%2F%28100+%28X%2B10+Y%2B1000%29%29%2BY-1%2F1000%3D0%5D

Answer (score 2):

As noted by Joe, this is actually a system of nonlinear equations.  You are going to need more firepower than numpy alone provides.

Solution of nonlinear equations is tricky, and the typical approach is to define an *objective function*

F(**z**) = sum( `e[n]`^2, n=1...13 )

where **z** is a vector containing a value for each of your 13 variables `a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,X,Y` and `e[n]` is the amount by which each of your 13 equations is violated.  For example

```
e[3] = (d - ((k * Y) / (1 + (j * X) + (k * Y))) * i  )
```

Once you have that objective function, then you can apply a nonlinear solver to try to find a  **z** for which F(**z**)=0.  That of course corresponds to a solution to your equations.

Commonly used solvers include:

- The Solver in Microsoft Excel
- The python library [scipy.optimize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html)
- Fitting routines in the [Gnu Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Nonlinear-Least_002dSquares-Fitting.html)
- Matlab's [optimization toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/optimization/)

Note that *all* of them will work far better if you first alter your set of equations to eliminate as many variables as practical before trying to run the solver (e.g. by substituting for `k` wherever it is found).  The reduced dimensionality makes a big difference.